# How to get started with Rail's gem sanitize, because I'm not able to make their quick start example work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitization, sanitize

I'm trying to sanitize some of the content inserted by my app's users using a rich text editor.

I have installed the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) via bundle install

and it appears on the list of gems installed, then added `require 'sanitize'` in application_controlled.rb

Added this test code in one of my views: `<%= Sanitize.fragment('<p>1st <strong>sanitized </strong>comment</p>', Sanitize::Config::RELAXED) %>` but the output is `<p>1st <strong>sanitized </strong>comment</p>` and I have no idea why or how to follow what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it.  `Sanitize::Config::RELAXED` allows `<p>` and `<strong>`.

To sanitize the string completely, skip the second argument.

```
<%= Sanitize.fragment('<p>1st <strong>sanitized </strong>comment</p>' %>

=> `1st sanitized comment`
```

If you're concerned that the string appears "as is" without escaping the tags, mark it as `html_safe`

```
<%= Sanitize.fragment('<p>1st <strong>sanitized </strong>comment</p>', Sanitize::Config::RELAXED).html_safe %>
```

=> 1st **sanitized** comment

Comment: Seems true. But, isn't the point of sanitize to apply `html_safe` itself ? I mean, isn't the purpose of sanitize to produce `html_safe` results, moreover when using its predifined configurations (BASIC, RELAXED...) ?

Comment: For me the point of `sanitize` is to remove possibly malicious HTML so that you can use `#html_safe` with some degree of confidence. As far as I know `sanitize` output as-is responds `false` with `#html_safe?` so you need that additional step.  Also, I'd tend to build the output string in the controller code, includinng the `#html_safe` so that checkers like `brakeman` don't give false positives.

Comment: I have 1 more question. As good practice, sanitizing output in the controller should simply be a matter of: `def show @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]) @comment.content = Sanitize.fragment(@comment.content).html_safe() end` ?

Comment: If you're using a rich text editor you'll lose all your editing that way.  Probably best to do the RELAXED filter. And I'd likely have a method in the model `#sanitized_content which will be `self.content` with `Sanitize.fragment` and `html_safe` applied.  Some would suggest you use a decorator model (see the `Draper` gem) but if it's just the one field then I'd happily stick the method in the model.

Comment: But then wouldn't it be too much, to sanitize the content before entering it into the database and once more before outputting it ? Is the extra measure of preotection worth the (little) extra computation/code for you ? I understand that that he database should be kept secure and if it happens to be compromized to have an extra protection for the output. I just thought 1 of either step would suffice. Thank you!

Comment: No, i wasn't saying you should sanitize it before you save it, i was saying the model could have a method `#sanitized_content`.  It would look like... `def sanitized_content; Sanitize.fragment(content, Sanitize::Config::RELAXED).html_safe; end`  That way whenever you display your model record, display `sanitized_content` instead of content and that will automatically sanitize the content for display.